# ActiveRecord: How to mark as duplicate and merge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have several external feeds providing data to my application's database. The problem is that sometimes what should be the instance is named slightly differently in two different feeds.

For example, one feed might use the name `Tom Cruise` while another might use `Thomas Cruise`. It's not a big deal, but the issue is that both end up with different associations depending on what feed they come from.

My question is: is there a way (or a gem) to be able to mark one as a duplicate of the other and merge all its associations to the canonical one?

Comment: Another example is `Something and something` vs `Something &amp; something`